# Rewrite two generic values to static

Tags: .htaccess

Hello I want to rewrite two values to static value on a link.
Sometimes link is like this: http://website.com/?s=page2
or like this: http://website.com/?m=page1&s=page2

I want to rewrite these links to these:
http://website.com/page2
http://website.com/page1/page2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# single parameter rule    
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?s=$1 [L,QSA]

# two parameters rule    
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?m=$1&s=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
It works but when I in second page (?m&s) style isnt working

Comment: That is due to relative paths in use. You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`